# How to increase the size of a structure when a addData(...) function is called, so that i can save more data

Tags: c++, structure

```
struct Database
{
    String _name;
    int _age;
    String _sex;
    String _email;
    String _eid;
    String _address;
    double _percentage;
};

class MyStudentDatabase
{
    public: MyStudentDatabase();~MyStudentDatabase();
    void addData(String name, int age, String sex, String email, String eid, String address, double percentage);

    private: int _iSize;
    Database * _pStructObject;
};
```

Here is the Definition Part -

```
MyStudentDatabase::MyStudentDatabase()
: _iSize(1)
{
    _pStructObject = new Database[_iSize];
}

MyStudentDatabase::~MyStudentDatabase()
{}

void MyStudentDatabase::addData(String name, int age, String sex, String email, String eid, String address, double percentage)
{
    _pStructObject[_iSize - 1]._name = name;
    _pStructObject[_iSize - 1]._sex = sex;
    _pStructObject[_iSize - 1]._email = email;
    _pStructObject[_iSize - 1]._eid = eid;
    _pStructObject[_iSize - 1]._address = address;
    _pStructObject[_iSize - 1]._percentage = percentage;
}
```

This program saves data only for one time , as the size of the Structure is `_iSize(1)`, so `_pStructObject[0]` is working for all the members, now i want to add another member and increase the size in that `addData(...)` function by `_iSize++`; but the problem is that if i do so , the previous data will get lost when i will use "new" operator inside the constructor. Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)!

Comment: use std::vector< DataBase >, it's a dynamic array so you can add/remove items as much as you like

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are trying to write your own container.  Unless this is homework, you should use one of the standard containers.  std::vector or std::list.

At the top:

```
#include <vector>
```

Instead of:

```
int _iSize;
Database * _pStructObject;
```

Use:

```
std::vector<Database> students;
```

And in your implementation:

```
void MyStudentDatabase::addData(String name, int age, String sex, String email, String eid, String address, double percentage)
{
  Database new_student;
  // fill out the new student here
  students.push_back(new_student);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use one of the container from the standard library?

You could use `std::vector<Database>` or `std::list<Database>` for example.
If you use a vector, you could also allocate your structures dynamically to avoid unnecessary structures copies when you need to resize it (i.e. `std::vector<Database*>`), or set its `capacity` in advance if you can.

STL documentation is available on cppreference.com or cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choises, one is use [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) (at background, STL continers of fixed size use it), internally that means that you reserve a new memory space, copy the information from the old memory space to the new one, and free the old one, or, you can use a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) that add a new node each time that you need (used by all list 'flavors' of STL).